# Cannot locate mysql instance in Solaris 10

Tags: mysql, solaris-10

I am working on a system setup by another admin. A solaris with a webstack setup. By using commands such as svcs -a|grep apache I can see apache running or svcs -a|grep postgresql shows me postgres is disabled. However svcs -a|grep mysql command does nothing. It just hops on the next line prompt waiting for an input! This mysql databases I can see are all located on this Solaris computer which is networked to a Fedora computer running other applications.
The windows clients networked to the Solaris however have the applications whcih are based on MYSQL running normal.
Anyone with a clue? I actually want to access the MYSQL commandline on Solaris but it says Mysql : not found!

Comment: I am suspecting the technician placed the mysql databases on Solaris but the actual MySQL server is accessing this databases remotely from Fedora but then why would the Fedora server not show me such a database if I type a command like  mysqlshow -u root -ppassword?

Answer (score 0):

svcs shows service if this serivce building with SMF (Service Management Facility).

In classic model service using control-scripts from /etc/init.d/

Error message "command not found" maybe occurred if your PATH variable does not contains paths where stored mysql, for example: /usr/local/bin/mysql.

If you are sure that a server with Solaris installed mysql - try find mysql file on your file system.

For find run command:
find / -type f -name mysql

Comment: The technician installed mysql and apache2 in some sort of virtual drive on solaris and the database is on the physical drive. I am yet to understand how he did this!